# Timestream Automatically refresh

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core, amazon-timestream

I am creating an application which takes values from an IOT device and then sends the values into IOT core AWS and then from AWS the data is sent to Timestream and from timestream the data is sent to Grafana DB, the problem I am facing is that for timestream I have to press the run for updating the new added values, is there any way I can automate this process

Iot core connection with Timestream and timestream not updating automatically